# Which descriptive statistics are sufficient?

Tags: statistics

I was recently asked to choose from the basic set of descriptive statistics which ones are sufficient.

**Mean
   Median
   Mode
   Standard deviation E. Variance
   Range
   IQR (or IR)
   Skewness
   Kurtosis**

This was a test question, and I guess I have the wrong idea about sufficiency because I was under the impression that it was on a *per-distribution* basis.

Can someone explain to me how to generally classify statistics as sufficient or not, and why? I'll also add that I am very new to statistics, and the only explination of sufficiency offered is that a stat uses all available data.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see my answer below; if you have additional questions on this topic, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

**Mean** is good when the data lacks major outliers. For example, if you had several outliers on the lower end of your data, it would push the mean down, so a more *robust* descriptive statistic in this case would be the **median**. The median is more robust to extreme outliers.

Likewise, **standard deviation** and **variance** are helpful when the mean is used for the same reason. Outliers would increase the spread, and therefore, increase these statistics. A more *robust* descriptive statistic would be the **IQR** which can illustrate the spread without being too spread out. Like the median, the IQR is robust to extreme outliers.

Hope this helps!